# How can I get an image to fit the whole screen in width, and have the full height be shown via scroll

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is 2500x3500 pixels, that I want to have as a background image for my website. When I set the background size to cover in css,

```
body {
    background-image: url(coolaid.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image properly scales to cover the website, but the bottom half gets cut off as it is a vertical image. How do I make it so that the entire image gets shown (make the page height fit according to the image)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to be able to scroll the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want image to be fully seen, then the ratio of the box has to match the ratio of the image :

```css
html {
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/2500x3500/) no-repeat red;
  background-size:cover;
  height:140vw;
}
```

how do i get the ratio ?

35/25 = 1.4

width is 100vw.

min-height should be :

100vw x 1.4 = 140vw

Comment: GC, I was expecting more than hard-coding the ratio in CSS :). Jk.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu what do you mean?, as a background , image doesn't exist :) you need either a script to retrieve image proportion or include it in the document to expand it... ??

Comment: I actually went the script way and stopped when I realized just by placing the img in body is enough, provided it's responsive (`position:absolute; width:100vw; height:auto`). So the script doesn't need to calculate the image. Only to create it and place it. Or, without any `js`, it can be placed there manually, as first child of `<body>`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu ah okay, yep that works too and very useful when ratio is unknown

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://beerhold.it/3500/2501);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
body
{
    background-image: url(coolaid.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
}
```